# Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?

Tags: html, http, https, uri, protocol-relative

I have the following element:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.example.com/js_file.js"></script>
```

In this case the site is HTTPS, but the site may also be just HTTP. (The JS file is on another domain.) I'm wondering if it's valid to do the following for convenience sake:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.example.com/js_file.js"></script>
```

I'm wondering if it's valid to remove the `http:` or `https:`?

It seems to work everywhere I have tested, but are there any cases where it doesn't work?

Comment: Can the "it seems to work everywhere" be generalised to images, iframes, link-rels etc etc? This is interesting stuff, if so.

Comment: Yup, it should work in any place that calls for a URI: images, links, etc.  It may be rare to see this in use, but it's perfectly valid.

Comment: Whats with all that instant upvoting guys? Not that the question is bad or anything, I'm just curious. But I bet Chris' intial reputation have an influence.

Comment: @Frederik: Because it's a fascinating and useful trick that most people are apparently unaware of.

Comment: @Frederik: What?

Comment: @Fred I haven't seen such a trend even after I crossed 10K

Comment: I don't exactly know **when** this happens, but i did get lots of these errors in my log: `[Fri May 15 17:14:09 2015] [error] [client 32.104.18.214] File does not exist: /www/html/ajax.googleapis.com, referer: http://example.com/something` - for that reason I switched back to adding the protocol

Comment: Here's a scenario where it doesnt work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161670/handling-404s-while-loading-cached-scripts-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URI starting with two slashes ... how do they behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071117/uri-starting-with-two-slashes-how-do-they-behave)

Answer (score 399, accepted):

A relative URL without a scheme (http: or https:) is valid, per [RFC 3986: "Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax", Section 4.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).  If a client chokes on it, then it's the client's fault because they're not complying with the URI syntax specified in the RFC.

Your example is valid and should work.  I've used that relative URL method myself on heavily trafficked sites and have had zero complaints.  Also, we test our sites in Firefox, Safari, IE6, IE7 and Opera.  These browsers all understand that URL format.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a relative URL in the question. It looks like an absolute URL that's missing the protocol.

Comment: It is indeed relative.  Take a look at RFC 3986, section 4.

Comment: I agree its relative, // == / relative begins with / absolute does not. So cdn.example.com/js_file.js is absolute but /cdn.example.com/js_file.js or //cdn.example.com/js_file.js is relative.

Comment: "If a client chokes on it, then it's the client's fault because they're not complying with the URI syntax specified in the RFC." -- I think this is an interesting question -- but whether a client follows "the spec" is hardly a good standard for whether it's wise to do in a web app.

Comment: Although this technique seems to be little known, it is supported in all the web browsers.  It works just great.

Comment: I wonder why google doesn't use this for analytics. They use the document.location.protocol method.

Comment: When they say relative URL, it means relative as in on the same protocol.

Comment: @Darryl Hein I believe google uses the document.location.protocol method because it also modifies the url, not only the scheme. They go to https://SSL.google-analytics.com if the document is using the https scheme.

Comment: google doesn't use this because Windows XP network stack doesn't support SNI. See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/12/07/certificate-name-mismatch-warnings-and-server-name-indication.aspx . Therefore allowing the google analytics script to be loaded through https on IE6 would result in a certificate error.

Comment: @Eilistraee, very nice find! I even think that's an answer in itself, as it is something to consider, despite this being 2012.

Comment: @Eilistraee the URL Google choose to use for their Analytics service has nothing to do with SNI. SNI is about having the server distinguishing requests to distinct hosts on the same IP address and port. `http://` and `https://` have distinct default ports already.

Comment: yes, but I was speaking of the use of the subdomain ssl.google-analytics.com by Google. It's because if they simply used https://google-analytics.com, the Google server would resolve the host through SNI, which doesn't work if using WinXP & IE. Therefore, they created the ssl.google-analytics.com subdomain.

Comment: I love this trick.  I should mention it can be a pain if you ever need to access the file from your filesystem.  Then the relative url resolves to the "file" scheme, which of course doesn't work.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that this standard doesn't validate on XHTML webpages.

Comment: I'm having same issue on my localhost. Everywhere else relative proto url works except localhost.

Comment: Does this Apply to img src tags?

Comment: @TOMP I believe it'll apply to anywhere you use a URL in HTML. `script`, `a`, `img`, etc.

Answer (score 157):

It is guaranteed to work in any mainstream browser (I'm not taking browsers with less than 0.05% market share into consideration). Heck, it works in Internet Explorer 3.0.

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) defines a URI as composed of the following parts:

```
     foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
     \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
      |           |            |            |        |
   scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
```

When defining relative URIs ([Section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2)), you can omit any of those sections, always starting from the left. In pseudo-code, it looks like this:

```
 result = ""

  if defined(scheme) then
     append scheme to result;
     append ":" to result;
  endif;

  if defined(authority) then
     append "//" to result;
     append authority to result;
  endif;

  append path to result;

  if defined(query) then
     append "?" to result;
     append query to result;
  endif;

  if defined(fragment) then
     append "#" to result;
     append fragment to result;
  endif;

  return result;
```

The URI you are describing is a scheme-less relative URI.

Comment: Yeah I guess I thought scheme and authority were always mutually dependent. It makes sense that it's not, but it's not something I've encountered until very recently.

Comment: It is not guaranteed to work in any browser.  It is guaranteed to work only in browsers that follow the RFC.

Comment: @Roger Pate: I have yet to see a browser not follow the RFC for URI. That particular standard has been around for so long... I've just tested it in IE3.0 and it understands it perfectly fine.

If you fall on a browser that doesn't understand those links, chances are it is such a marginal browser that it won't matter.

Comment: @Andrew: Maybe you differ from me, but when I say "guarantee" in the context of programming, I really mean "there is no way this can possibly, ever fail," not just "it only works in popular implementations that I've tested."  I didn't mean to make a big deal out of it, but it seemed important enough to mention.

Comment: @Roger: Yes, but in the context of web development, marginal browsers (<0.01% market share) are not taken into consideration. It's like saying that an API is present in all versions of Windows and then someone comes it to say that it might not be supported in Wine...

Comment: @Kugel: Yes, Python is readable. :) -- @Andrew: Marginal browsers like IE7&8? SLaks points out how they have problems using these URLs, which is the type of nuance hidden by "guaranteed to work" in a technical context.  All you have to say is "RFC 3986 requires this behavior, which all mainstream browsers handle," but that's already said on the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/) anyway.

Comment: @Roger Pate: Loading a CSS file twice doesn't break a site. It's a minor inconvenience that technical users won't notice anyway. And you should know that nothing is guaranteed in IT anyway. There are always edge cases.

Comment: Great diagram there. Given that diagram I wonder in what way src="//youtube.com" is different from src="youtube.com"? Why would you use the former instead of the latter in any case? Does it matter at all or are they semantically identically?

Comment: @SteveMidgley: `youtube.com` points to a file/directory called "youtube.com" relative to the current URL. `//youtube.com` points to the domain "youtube.com" on the same scheme the current URL is using. They are not the same at all.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Moore. Brainfreeze on my end. Thinking of browsers which sub the protocol in when you type the URL! Duh. For src="... obviously you have to specify the protocol so // is a very useful nomenclature.

Comment: Awesome graph showing the parts of the URI. Very concise in explanation

Answer (score 82):

> are there any cases where it doesn't work?

If the parent page was loaded from `file://`, then it probably does not work (it will try to get `file://cdn.example.com/js_file.js`, which of course you could provide locally as well).

Comment: A must know for guys testing html on local machine!

Comment: argh... no wonder my `script src="//..."` wasn't working! I was opening the html file locally!

Comment: Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: @ogc-nick: You can run a local web server. Plenty options these days, with zero configuration. You want that anyway, as many other things (such as XHR or web workers also don't work for the file: domain)

Comment: @Thilo That has been working temporarily for me but I am making an app with Github's Electron and that gets a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 41):

Many people call this a Protocol Relative URL.

[It causes a double-download of CSS files in IE 7 & 8](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/02/10/5a-missing-schema-double-download/).

Comment: @AndrewMoore As the "thing" being excluded indicates the web protocol, calling it "protocol relative" makes more sense. I've never heard of ftp or http being called "schemes"...

Answer (score 27):

Here I duplicate the answer in [Hidden features of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954327/hidden-features-of-html/960111#960111):

> Using a protocol-independent absolute
>   path:
>
> ```
> <img src="//domain.com/img/logo.png"/>
> ```
>
> If the browser is viewing an page in
>   SSL through HTTPS, then it'll request
>   that asset with the https protocol,
>   otherwise it'll request it with HTTP.
>
> This prevents that awful "This Page
>   Contains Both Secure and Non-Secure
>   Items" error message in IE, keeping
>   all your asset requests within the
>   same protocol.
>
> Caveat: When used on a `<link>` or
>   @import for a stylesheet, IE7 and IE8
>   [download the file twice](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/02/10/5a-missing-schema-double-download/). All other
>   uses, however, are just fine.

Answer (score 17):

It is perfectly valid to leave off the protocol.  The URL spec has been very clear about this for years, and I've yet to find a browser that doesn't understand it.  I don't know why this technique isn't better known; it's the perfect solution to the thorny problem of crossing HTTP/HTTPS boundaries.  More here: [Http-https transitions and relative URLs](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200710/httphttps_transitions_and_relative_urls.html)

Answer (score 10):

> are there any cases where it doesn't work?

Just to throw this in the mix, if you are developing on a local server, it might not work. You need to specify a scheme, otherwise the browser may assume that `src="//cdn.example.com/js_file.js"` is `src="file://cdn.example.com/js_file.js"`, which will break since you're not hosting this resource locally.

Microsoft Internet Explorer seem to be particularly sensitive to this, see this question: [Not able to load jQuery in Internet Explorer on localhost (WAMP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082846/not-able-to-load-jquery-in-internet-explorer-on-localhost-wamp)

You would probably always try to find a solution that works on all your environments with the least amount of modifications needed.

The solution used by [HTML5Boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/) is to have a fallback when the resource is not loaded correctly, but that only works if you incorporate a check:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- If jQuery is not defined, something went wrong and we'll load the local file -->
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

UPDATE: [HTML5Boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/) now uses `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` after deciding to deprecate protocol relative URLs, see [here][3].

Answer (score 7):

### 1. Summary

Answer for 2019: you can still use protocol-relative URLs, but [**this technique**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48893712/5951529) [**an anti-pattern**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454204/5951529).

Also:

1. You may have problems in developing.
2. Some third-party tools may not support them.

Migrating from protocol-relative URLs to `https://` it would be nice.

---

### 2. Relevance

This answer is relevant for January 2019. In the future, the data of this answer may be obsolete.

---

### 3. Anti-pattern

#### 3.1. Argumentation

Paul Irish — [**front-end engineer and a developer advocate for the Google Chrome**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Irish) — [**write in 2014, December**](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/):

> Now that SSL is [**encouraged for everyone**](https://www.eff.org/encrypt-the-web-report) and [**doesn’t have performance concerns**](https://istlsfastyet.com/), **this technique is now an anti-pattern**. If the asset you need is available on SSL, then always use the `https://` asset.
>
> Allowing the snippet to request over HTTP opens the door for attacks like the [**recent GitHub Man-on-the-side attack**](https://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2015-03&post=China%27s-Man-on-the-Side-Attack-on-GitHub). It’s always safe to request HTTPS assets even if your site is on HTTP, however the reverse [**is not true**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content).

#### 3.2. Another links

- [**Loads page resources using protocol relative URIs**](https://sitebulb.com/hints/security/loads-page-resources-using-protocol-relative-uris/)
- [**Stop using protocol-relative URLs**](https://joonas.fi/2016/12/27/stop-using-protocol-relative-urls/)

#### 3.3. Examples

- [**In 2017 Stack Overflow switched from protocol-relative URLs to `https`**](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/#mistakes-protocol-relative-urls)
- [**In 2018 Chrome will flag all unencrypted websites as “not secure”**](https://www.techradar.com/news/from-july-chrome-will-flag-all-unencrypted-websites-as-not-secure)

---

### 4. Developing process

For example, I try to use [**clean-console**](https://github.com/bahmutov/clean-console).

- Example file `KiraCleanConsole__cdn_links_demo.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>clean-console without protocol demonstration</title>
    <!-- Really dead link -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bowser@latest/bowser.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Package exists; link without “https:” -->
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Package exists: link with “https:” -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gemini-scrollbar/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Kira Goddess!
</body>
</html>
```

- output:

```text
D:\SashaDebugging>clean-console -i KiraCleanConsole__cdn_links_demo.html
checking KiraCleanConsole__cdn_links_demo.html
phantomjs: opening page KiraCleanConsole__cdn_links_demo.html

phantomjs: Unable to load resource (#3URL:file://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js)


phantomjs:   phantomjs://code/runner.js:30 in onResourceError
Error code: 203. Description: Error opening //cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js: The network path was not found.

  phantomjs://code/runner.js:31 in onResourceError

phantomjs: Unable to load resource (#5URL:https://unpkg.com/bowser@2.1.0/bowser.min.js)


phantomjs:   phantomjs://code/runner.js:30 in onResourceError
Error code: 203. Description: Error downloading https://unpkg.com/bowser@2.1.0/bowser.min.js - server replied: Not Found

  phantomjs://code/runner.js:31 in onResourceError

phantomjs: Checking errors after sleeping for 1000ms
2 error(s) on KiraCleanConsole__cdn_links_demo.html

phantomjs process exited with code 2
```

Link `//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js` is valid, but I getting an error.

Pay attention to `file://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js` and read [**Thilo**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7818464/5951529) and [**bg17aw**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37609402/5951529) answers about `file://`.

I didn't know about this behavior and couldn't understand why I have problems like [**this for pageres**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres/issues/331).

---

### 5. Third-party tools

I use [**Clickable URLs**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Clickable%20URLs) Sublime Text package. Use it, I can simply open links from my text editor in browser.

[image: CSS links examples]

Both links in example are valid. But first link I can successfully open in browser use Clickable URLs, second link — no. This may not be very convenient.

---

### 6. Conclusion

Yes:

1. If you have problems as in `Developing process` item, you can set your development workflow.
2. Else you have problems as in `Third-party tools` item, you can contribute tools.

But you don't need this additional problems. Read information by links in `Anti-pattern` item: protocol-relative URLs is obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

Following the gnud's reference, the **RFC 3986 section 5.2** says:

> If the scheme component is defined, indicating that the reference
>   starts with a scheme name, then the reference is interpreted as an
>   absolute URI and we are done. **Otherwise, the reference URI's scheme
>   is inherited from the base URI's scheme component**.

So `//` is correct :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is documented in [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), section 5.2:

(edit: Oops, my RFC reference was outdated).

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed correct, as other answers have stated. You should note though, that some web crawlers will set off 404s for these by requesting them on your server as if a local URL. (They disregard the double slash and treat it as a single slash).

You may want to set up a rule on your webserver to catch these and redirect them.

For example, with Nginx, you'd add something like:

```
location ~* /(?<redirect_domain>((([a-z]|[0-9]|\-)+)\.)+([a-z])+)/(?<redirect_path>.*) {
  return 301 $scheme:/$redirect_domain/$redirect_path;
}
```

Do note though, that if you use periods in your URIs, you'll need to increase the specificity or it will end up redirecting those pages to nonexistent domains.

Also, this is a rather massive regex to be running for each query -- in my opinion, it's worth punishing non-compliant browsers with 404s over a (slight) performance hit on the majority of compliant browsers.

Answer (score 3):

We are seeing 404 errors in our logs when using //somedomain.com as references to JS files.

The references that cause the 404s come out looking like this:
ref:

```
<script src="//somedomain.com/somescript.js" />
```

404 request:

```
http://mydomain.com//somedomain.com/somescript.js
```

With these showing up regularly in our web server logs, it is safe to say that: All browsers and Bots **DO NOT** honor RFC 3986 section 4.2. The safest bet is to include the protocol whenever possible.

Comment: Yeah, I've kinda of switched away from it, but not because of 404s (I've never seen any 404s...if a bot doesn't honour it, I could care less) – because I no longer load resources from other CDNs so I don't have a need to do this (instead I minify as much as possible into 1 or 2 files).

Comment: Please include the protocol. Protocol-less refs break in my Cordova app.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern I see on [html5-boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate) is:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

It runs smoothly on different schemes like `http`, `https`, `file`.

Comment: This is no longer true, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37609402/2237601 or [here](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/pull/1694/commits/045a1676c4c8cf4bdd23374b5b049507101f5043), they now use `https://` for everything

Comment: @bg17aw The problem with using `https://` everywhere is that you then have to keep checking all your external links to see if they actually support it, and change them to `http://` if they do not (as otherwise they will not work). This may be troublesome with a large number of links.

Comment: @tomasz86 you are missing the point, I was only reffering to the particular case of linking to content from CDNs. https:// is mandatory for that nowadays. The answer also talks about a particular case (html5-boilerplate). There is no "checking for http" as you say, as CDNs always use https now.

Comment: @bg17aw That is true but the general question here is not only about CDNs. By reading just this answer/comment it is easy to think that `https://` should (or can) be used in all links which is not correct.

Comment: @tomasz86 The beauty of having multiple answers is that while none of them is perfect (if an answer would be perfect, the others would need to be deleted), reading a few of them gives us a broader view. In this case, the answer says "the pattern on html5boilerplate is..." and my comment updates this answer mentioning "that is no longer the pattern on html5-boilerplate". That's it. A needed addition to this particular answer. Also please note the original question is indeed about CDNs!

Answer (score 1):

As your example is linking to an external domain, if you are using HTTPS then you should verify that the external domain is setup for SSL as well. Otherwise, your users may see SSL errors and/or 404 errors (e.g. older versions of Plesk store HTTP and HTTPS in separate folders). For CDNs, it shouldn't be an issue but for any other website it could be.

On a side note, tested while updated an old website and also works in the url= part of a META REFRESH.