# Using // in a <script>'s source

Tags: javascript, http, url, https

I was wondering if anyone had any resources, proof, or personal experience in using the age-old http/https JavaScript `<script>` hack:

```
<script src="//someserver.com/js/script.js"></script>
```

Has anyone encountered issues in any of these browsers (IE 5.5+, FF2+, Chrome, Opera 9+, Safari 3+)?  Has anybody had success stories?

Comment: What does this hack do? Uses http/https accordingly with the referrer url? Why don't you just use /, instead of //?

Comment: @Spidey: Actually, it is not a hack. It is a perfectly valid relative URI syntax. This is very useful when switching between http and https, because there would be no need to specify the protocol. Using just `/` wouldn't work in this case, because the OP is requesting the script from a separate domain.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-srchttp

Comment: you're right, Darryl, it is a duplicate.  thank you for pointing out where everybody else got the answer, :P (just kidding Daniel / wilmoore).

Comment: By the way, there are some downsides to this - in older browser (IE7-8, I believe) you'll double download some resources due to a bug in IE's network cache (it treats //domain.tld/foo.file differently than http://domain.tld/foo.file). http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/02/10/5a-missing-schema-double-download/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All modern browsers will understand that format, including IE 6. (Not sure about IE 5.5).

Actually, this is not a hack, but a perfectly valid URI syntax as per [RFC 3986: Section 4.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). Therefore, I say you're good to go.

Comment: You're calling IE6 a modern browser? LOL! +1 EDIT: Damn, out of votes :(

Answer (score 9):

I can point you to exactly what you are looking for. It is an RFC document so you have to sift through a lot of noise to get to what you want but this is a legit *feature* (not a hack) of supposed http clients.

```
       b) If the embedded URL starts with a scheme name, it is
          interpreted as an absolute URL and we are done.

       c) Otherwise, the embedded URL inherits the scheme of
          the base URL.
```

Read more: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1808.html (search for the heading "Resolving Relative URLs" and see steps 1 and 2 below) or here: http://freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1808/18.htm

As an FYI, I use this in pretty much all of my production projects -- not just for JS resources, but for links to other resources such as images and CSS (UPDATED: I no longer use this for linking stylesheets).

Works pretty much everywhere. I've tried this in IE, FF, Opera, Chrome, Safari/Webkit all going back multiple previous versions (where applicable).

Examples:

- < img src="//static.example.com/img/token.png" />
- < script type="text/javascript" src="//static.example.com/js/jquery.js">

I find this method to be cleaner than writing code to figure out if we are on http/https.

The only caveat is that you should not use this for stylesheets.

While the following is legal and works:

- < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//static.example.com/css/screen.css" media="screen" />

In IE, the above will cause two HTTP requests. Currently, this affects IE7, IE8, and early versions of IE9.

**In other words, scheme relative URIs should/can be used for all resources except stylesheets.**

Answer (score 2):

I have been using this schema since I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-srchttp) and I haven't had any problems. I've seen it work in every browser, including IE5.5. (Most of the stuff I work on requires JavaScript and some of the JS is included with this method.)

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps the reason people get confused about this is that Google Analytics' standard code inclusion does some complicated stuff with the hostname based on the protocol. However I suspect this is due to the fact that their SSL hostname is different to the non-SSL hostname, for some network reason I imagine.