# How can I refactor these script tags?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I have the following script tags in the `<head>` so that they don't prompt any security errors when going back and forth between SSL and non-SSL pages. But it just looks hairy.

Any way I can combine them or reduce some of the code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(["\<script src='",("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://","ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'>\<\/script>"].join(''));</script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(["\<script src='",("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://","html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js' type='text/javascript'>\<\/script>"].join(''));</script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(["\<script src='",("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://","use.typekit.com/12345.js' type='text/javascript'>\<\/script>"].join(''));</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All modern browsers will understand the *Relative Reference* URI format, which will work automatically for both the `http` and `https` [URI scheme names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme):

```
<script src="//example.com/path/script.js"></script>
```

Further reading:

- [RFC 3986: Section 4.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)
- [Stack Overflow: Using // in a script's source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458735/using-in-a-scripts-source)
- [Stack Overflow: Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a script src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-srchttp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Create a closure for our loadScript-function
  var loadScript = (function () {
       var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
           scriptTagTemplate = document.createElement('script'),
           addEventListener = function (type, element, listener) {
              if(element.addEventListener) {
                 element.addEventListener(type, listener);
                 return true;
              }
              else if (element.attachEvent) {
                 element.attachEvent('on'+type, listener);
                 return true;
              }
              return false;
           };
       scriptTagTemplate.type = 'text/javascript';

       // This function clones the script template element and appends it to head
       // It takes an uri on the form www.example.com/path, and an optional
       // callback to invoke when the resource is loaded.
       return function (uri, callback) {
          var scriptTag = scriptTagTemplate.cloneNode(true);
          if (callback) {
              addEventListener('load', scriptTag, callback);
          }
          headTag.appendChild(scriptTag);
          scriptTag.src = ['//', uri].join('');
       }
    }());
</script>
```

Now you can use the function like so:

```
<script>
        loadScript('ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js');
        loadScript('html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js');
        loadScript('use.typekit.com/12345.js');
</script>
```

The strength of this solution is that you avoid using `document.write` which is error-prone and blocking. You also get an option to have a callback invoked once the script is loaded.