# Is it safe to use current protocol (//) everywhere in HTML?

Tags: html, url, protocols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Absolute URLs omitting the protocol (scheme) in order to preserve the one of the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the)

Assuming website can be accessed only through HTTP protocol, are these two blocks of code  100% identical and compatible in all browsers?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com">
<script src="http://example.com"></script>
<form action="http://example.com">
<img src="http://example.com">
<a href="http://example.com"></a>
```

Is it the same as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//example.com">
<script src="//example.com"></script>
<form action="//example.com">
<img src="//example.com">
<a href="//example.com"></a>
```

I did a quick test and they all seem to be working (in FF), but I couldn't find any research material on this topic. Are there any limitation? Any pitfalls? Any reasons not to do it?

Comment: another dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just