# Urls with two leading slashes and without schema

Tags: html

Sometimes I see script src or image src without schema, only two leading slashes //

From http://www.performable.com/ home page

```
<script src="//d2f7h8c8hc0u7y.cloudfront.net/performable/pax/8uEvsz.js"></script>
```

http://www.hellobar.com/ home page - and their integration code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.hellobar.com/hellobar.js"></script>
```

I've integrated both on my site and see errors in apache log similar to

```
www.mysite.com//www.hellobar.com/hellobar.js not found
```

However they're rare - less than 1%.

I think double leading slashes is a replacement for http\https and such links will use current page schema. Can someone confirm that?

Also, which browsers have support for that urls and which have problems?

Comment: possible duplicate of [URI starting with two slashes ... how do they behave?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071117/uri-starting-with-two-slashes-how-do-they-behave)

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate. Unfortunately, google don't search by //

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute URLs omitting the protocol (scheme) in order to preserve the one of the current page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URI starting with two slashes ... how do they behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071117/uri-starting-with-two-slashes-how-do-they-behave)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was discussed multiple times here. Yes it is safe and yes all browsers support this.