# Are there situations where omitting the protocol in http:// or https:// will fail to work in certain browsers?

Tags: html, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change all my  links to just //?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just)

I.e. if I do: `//www.google.com` it would point to `http://www.google.com` or `https://www.google.com` depending on what the current protocol is. Are there browsers that is reasonable to support where this doesn't work, if so which?

Comment: It's by definition unreasonable to support a browser that doesn't conform to RFC 1808.

Comment: just want to check that https:///, note three /s is intentional or not?

Comment: @ngen - Oh it definitely works. :)

Comment: @Jon P - Thanks for catching that, fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This **would work** on all browsers according to [RFC 3986 Section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2). They call it relative reference.

Further more I have seen good JavaScript coders using it / recommending it

1. [The protocol-relative URL by Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)
2. [Cripple the Google CDN’s caching with a single character by Dave Ward](http://encosia.com/cripple-the-google-cdns-caching-with-a-single-character/)

Furthermore you can find related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the).

Comment: Oh thanks for the RFC link, I'll put that on my to-read list for sure.