# URL without "http|https"

Tags: http, url, https

I just learned from a colleague that omitting the "http | https" part of a URL in a link will make that URL use whatever scheme the page it's on uses.

So for example, if my page is accessed at http://www.example.com and I have a link (notice the '//' at the front):

```
<a href="//www.google.com">Google</a>
```

That link will go to http://www.google.com.

But if I access the page at https://www.example.com with the same link, it will go to https://www.google.com

I wanted to look online for more information about this, but I'm having trouble thinking of a good search phrase.  If I search for "URLs without HTTP" the pages returned are about urls with this form: "www.example.com", which is not what I'm looking for.

Would you call that a schemeless URL?  A protocol-less URL?

Does this work in all browsers?  I tested it in FF and IE 8 and it worked in both.  Is this part of a standard, or should I test more browsers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute URLs omitting the protocol (scheme) in order to preserve the one of the current page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the)

Comment: For reference (since you asked what terms to search), the Google search which brought me to the original StackOverflow question was: "absolute url without protocol"

Comment: you're not specifying if its an http or https so the browser decides for you by taking the last page assuming that the link came from the same page.

Comment: Thanks David, the link to the duplicate answered all my questions

Comment: @David: To be exactly, you wouldn’t call it an absolute URL if it doesn’t have a protocol; it’s rather a relative URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change all my http:// links to just //?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**Protocol relative URL**

You may receive unusual security warnings in some browsers.

See also, [Wikipedia Protocol-relative URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#prurl) for a brief definition.

At one time, [it was recommended](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/); but going forward, [it should be avoided](https://web.archive.org/web/20161220005605/https://jeremywagner.me/blog/stop-using-the-protocol-relative-url/).

See also the Stack Overflow question [Why use protocol-relative URLs at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446314/why-use-protocol-relative-urls-at-all).

Answer (score 21):

It is called **network-path reference** (the part that is missing is called `scheme` or `protocol`) [defined in RFC3986 Section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2)

> 4.2 Relative Reference
>
> A relative reference takes advantage of the hierarchical syntax
> (Section 1.2.3) to express a URI reference relative to the name space
> of another hierarchical URI.
>
> ```
>   relative-ref  = relative-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
>
>   relative-part = "//" authority path-abempty
>                 / path-absolute
>                 / path-noscheme
>                 / path-empty
> ```
>
> The URI referred to by a relative reference, also known as the  target    URI, is obtained by applying the reference resolution
> algorithm of    Section 5.
>
> **A relative reference that begins with two slash characters is
> termed a network-path reference** (emphasis mine); such references are rarely used.
> A    relative reference that begins with a single slash character is  termed an absolute-path reference.  A relative reference that does    not begin with a slash character is termed a relative-path reference.
>
> A path segment that contains a colon character (e.g., "this:that")  cannot be used as the first segment of a relative-path reference, as   it would be mistaken for a scheme name.  Such a segment must be    preceded by a dot-segment (e.g., "./this:that") to make a relative-    path reference.

Comment: // can't be used in base tag in html. I set <base href="//abc.com/" and a relative image url <img src="/img/logo.jpg>. However, opened on browser, the image link will become file:///abc.com/img/logo.jpg. Any workaround?