# Why won't JavaScript run on GitHub pages?

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-pages

My JavaScript code does not run on GitPages. It should display a background slideshow, but instead... does nothing. [Other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852819/javascript-wont-run-on-github-pages-site) experiencing the same issue mostly fix their problem by using the https protocol instead of of http.

However, I'm using relative filepaths 
`src="js/script.js"`.

I've tried using https protocol with relative filepaths
`src="https://js/script.js`.

I've tried using https protocol with absolute filepaths
`src="https://github.com/absolute_path/js/script.js"`

I've tried embedding the script in the html document itself, rather than calling an external file
`<script>
JavaScript code
</script>`

*All* of these work fine on my local machine, but *none* of them work on GitPages. The rest of the site works fine, including CSS--it's just the JavaScript that's not working. I'm new to GitHub and have no experience with JavaScript, so your help and patience is greatly appreciated.

GitPages [page](https://gwyncase.github.io/NorthernGoshawkProject/) and [repository](https://github.com/GwynCase/NorthernGoshawkProject/tree/master/docs)

Comment: All of your images are returning 404's

Comment: There's no script called `script.js` in `./js/`. And there's no script tag importing the script in `index.html`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your images are named `1.JPG` in the repository but are referenced as `1.jpg` in your CSS.  Github file paths are case-sensitive, so you need make "jpg" uppercase in `slide.css`.  Your js (only modernizr.js) appears to be loading fine.

If you are using a mac, your local filesystem is case insensitive so it would work fine locally.

Comment: Just about to post the same answer! +1