# Performance difference - loading google maps using relative vs absolute path

Tags: relative-path, absolute-path

Would there be any sort of performance difference if I implement maps.google on the client side using relative path? Would it be faster with an absolute path?

I'm wondering after reading the article: https://jeremywagner.me/blog/stop-using-the-protocol-relative-url

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very similar to
[Why use protocol-relative URLs at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446314/why-use-protocol-relative-urls-at-all)

There are many discussion about perfomance of it.