# Difference between //www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js and https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am reading https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ and this is the JavaScript tracking snippet they provide:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new 
Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-
analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

In one of my implementations, I have the code with the only difference that instead of `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js` I am using `//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js`, but everything works correctly. Does it matter to include `https:` at the beginning. What would be the difference between using one form or the other? Thank you.

Comment: Using `src="//example.com"` instructs the browser to match the protocol, it's called "protocol relative url". See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446314/

Comment: And the difference _in this particular case_ would be that if your website is not served over https the browser needs to follow a redirect (since google redirects to the https version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "protocol relative url."  You can [read about them here](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/), but you should really just be using https at this point.

Here's a good excerpt from the linked resource:

> Now that SSL is encouraged for everyone and doesn’t have performance
>   concerns, this technique is now an anti-pattern. If the asset you need
>   is available on SSL, then always use the https:// asset.
>
> Allowing the snippet to request over HTTP opens the door for attacks
>   like the recent Github Man-on-the-side attack. It’s always safe to
>   request HTTPS assets even if your site is on HTTP, however the reverse
>   is not true.