# Link to an outside URL in my React application

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm still pretty new to React and web development in general. I'm building my personal portfolio website and wanted to do in in React so I could get more practice. I want to add a link to both my GitHub and my LinkedIn and all the research I've done has told me to use an `<a>` tag, but instead of going to my LinkedIn or GitHub it just tacks on the link to the rest of the url of my portfolio site.

```
import React from 'react'

export default () => {
  return (
    <div className='foot'>
      <p>website created by Thomas Gutierrez</p>

      <p><a href="www.linkedin.com/in/tg308">linkdin</a> : 
         <a href="www.github.com/tomg308">github</a></p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the HTTP(s) protocol to your URLs.

```
href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/tg308"
```

This tells the browser to redirect to a whole other page because it is an *absolute URL* because it specifies the scheme (HTTPS in this case).

Comment: You can also leave out the protocol and do `href="//www.linkedin.com/in/tg308"` if you aren't unsure if it's HTTP or HTTPS

Comment: @SungKim See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446314/why-use-protocol-relative-urls-at-all