# Removing https:// protocol from Jekyll Posts

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I am attempting to provide links in my Jekyll _posts that do not follow the https protocol. Currently when clicking on the links provided in my posts https:// is added to all URLs and this is causing protocol errors with any links not following the https protocol.

Here is how I am currently adding my _posts links to my website:

```
{% if post.website %}
  <li>View Website at:
    <strong>
      <a href="//{{ post.website }}" target=_blank>{{ post.websitename }}</a>
    </strong>
  </li>
{% endif %}
```

I have read that the browser will always use whatever the current protocol is and adding `//` to the front of any link should fix this. I attempted to add `//` to the link in the post itself, and directly to the html as shown above, neither of these fixes have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol less url (//:example.com) was supposed to enforce `https` for pages resources (css, js, img, ...), depending on the protocol used to serve the main document.

This was a transitional trick and [it's not state of the art anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454204/1548376).

Now, for a lot of good reasons, any `http` transfer must be done over `https`. [Privacy and integrity are our main concerns here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS).

If you want to make a link to an external site from a website front matter, it's up to you to :

- link to an `http` page : **NOT SECURED FOR USER**
- choose to **only** link to secured `https` pages : **A LITTLE MORE SECURE**

So, definitely, you front matter variable must look like

```
---
title: My great title
website: https://example.com
---
```

And your liquid code :

```
<a href="{{ post.website }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{ post.websitename }}</a>
```

Note the [noopener noreferrer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15551842/1548376).