# Error: Mixed Content, While Deploying React app on Github

Tags: reactjs, api, omdbapi

I ran into a small problem while deploying a react app on GitHub pages. The app works perfectly fine on a live server. But, when I push the code on gitHub and test it. This error occurs:

```
Mixed Content: the page at '<domain>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoing 'http://www.omdbapi.com/...' ...
```

I know it has something to do with the api I m using. It's [omdb api and uses HTTP protocol](https://www.omdbapi.com/) for a get request.  I tried changing the HTTP to https and though it works on the live server. [It does not on the Github page](https://www.omdbapi.com/), giving me the same error as before.

Code:

```
const apirul = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=...';
// ...
Axios(apiurl + "&=s="+state.s)
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  let results = data.Search;
  setState(prevState => {
    return { ...prevState, results }
  })
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log(e)
})
// ...
```

Comment: Images of code are not acceptable here. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why. Code is text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your question, as can the text of error messages. Please [edit] your post to provide that here. For more information, see [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [GitHub Pages](https://vaasu-dhand.github.io/Movie-Database-React/) and the source it's got, I suspect your push to GitHub failed as the code in the repo is still pointing to `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=ad5bdfd0` (and was last updated 17 hours ago).  I took [a screenshot to to confirm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23SaW.png).

Changing it the URL to `https://` should fix it, though you *could* use a protocol relative url (that is, `//`) if you had to.  [Really, you should be using https for everything now, even local development.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454204/80572)