# My <a href=""></a> isn't working?

Tags: html, href

I got this template online and Im making a portfolio using it. 
There are twitter/facebook/linkedin icons on the bottom right of the page which I'm trying to link to my accounts. Originally the href was set to "#", now when I try to set it to anything, it doesn't work. When I click on the icon, it does nothing.

```html
<footer>
    <ul class="icons">
       <li><a href="www.twitter.com" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-github"><span class="label">Github</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: What do you expect it to do? `href="#"` won't navigate anywhere. And when you replace it with what else *specifically*, what do you replace it with and what doesn't work? If you use "twitter.com" that won't work, for example, you need to include the protocol.

Comment: Is there javascript involved? If so, check the click handlers and look for  `e.preventDefault()` or `return false`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161769/url-without-httphttps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<footer>
    <ul class="icons">
       <li><a href="https://twitter.com" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://facebook.com" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://instagram.com" class="icon fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com" class="icon fa-github"><span class="label">Github</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:YOUR_EMAIL_ADDR" class="icon fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

Try this.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is you're working on this locally and its trying to serve `www.twitter.com` from your local drive.

For one, prefix your URL links with `//`. So the Twitter link will become `//www.twitter.com`. This will use whatever protocol (`http` or `https`) you're currently using.

You might also need to have it served from a http server for the URL to work. There are many options out there. One simple method, if you're on a Mac is to navigate in terminal to the directory where the file is, then type:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

This will start a simple HTTP server and your link will work.

```html
<footer>
  <ul class="icons">
    <li><a href="//www.twitter.com" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-github"><span class="label">Github</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```