# Removing the http protocol from an image URL?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, http

I'm looking at this code that removes `http` from the image URL and wondering why they are doing that?:

```
  get thumbnail(): string | boolean {
    if (this.book.volumeInfo.imageLinks) {
      return this.book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail.replace(
        'http:',
        ''
      );
    }
```

The corresponding angular template looks like this:

```
<img mat-card-sm-image *ngIf="thumbnail" [src]="thumbnail"/>
```

This is the complete stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-books-store-refactor-fullscreen?file=example-app%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Fcomponents%2Fbook-preview.component.ts

In case anyone is curious the image url is contained on a google books API JSON document like this one:

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/tI5UswEACAAJ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL without "http|https"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161769/url-without-httphttps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is removing the http from it so the url becomes a Protocol Relative URL. So if the page is under https:// it will load it from https instead of http.