# DataTable library not establishing on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to incorporate datatable to my table. Continuously it gives error as `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function`. I am trying on this since 4 hours now. Not having any clue, tried on every possible combinations but the error just not going and the table is not transforming into a datatable. The order by which I am putting my CDN's are,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

And just after `</table>` i am calling the function

```
<script>

  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
    </script>
```

Can somebody please help me out. Just have gone blank on this now and completely clueless.

Comment: How is your HTML file looks? Could you share it for us?

Comment: A couple of points (probably not fixes): (1) Don't use `href="//cdn.datatables.net/...`. Always [include the protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161769/url-without-httphttps) as well: `href="https://cdn.datatables.net/...`. (2) That version of jQuery (1.11.3) is extremely old - all the way from 2014. Try the latest version (3.5.1).