# Why ModSecurity blocks external links?

Tags: security, hyperlink, plesk, web-application-firewall

I am the owner of the website [www.getslim.guide](http://www.getslim.guide). There are two icons, which are linked. One to Tiktok, the other one to Youtube.

If click one of them, a new browser tab open with this link: https://getslim.guide/www.tiktok.com/@getslim.guide

But: [www.tiktok.com/@getslim.guide](http://www.tiktok.com/@getslim.guide) is the right link.

In my Web Application Firewall I see this Error:

[client 84.115.230.189] ModSecurity: Warning. String match within ".asa/ .asax/ .ascx/ .axd/ .backup/ .bak/ .bat/ .cdx/ .cer/ .cfg/ .cmd/ .com/ .config/ .conf/ .cs/ .csproj/ .csr/ .dat/ .db/ .dbf/ .dll/ .dos/ .htr/ .htw/ .ida/ .idc/ .idq/ .inc/ .ini/ .key/ .licx/ .lnk/ .log/ .mdb/ .old/ .pass/ .pdb/ .pol/ .printer/ .pwd/ .rdb/ .resources/ .resx/ .sql/ .swp/ .sys/ .vb/ .vbs/ .vbproj/ .vsdisco/ .webinfo/ .xsd/ .xsx/" at TX:extension. [file "/etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.d/rules/owasp_modsecurity_crs_3-plesk/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "476"] [id "920440"] [msg "URL file extension is restricted by policy"] [data ".com"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/210/272"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] [hostname "getslim.guide"] [uri "/youtube.com"] [unique_id "YUJutQi5rjI6cof4-eL39QAAAIM"]

What does it mean?

Best regards,

Nino

Comment: What is the exact link you used in HTM? Make sure you provide a full link including scheme like `<a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@getslim.guide">`

Comment: Hi Robert, this is the source code:

<section class="result">
<p>Get to know the easiest, healthiest and most effective weight loss program. Regardless of time and place. Without giving up delicious food, you will feel the first successes within 24 hours.<br>
<a href="www.tiktok.com/@getslim.guide" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img src="img/tik-tok.png" alt=""></a>
<a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img src="img/youtube.png" alt=""></a>
</section>

Comment: As I wrote your URL is defect. Make it fully qualified including scheme as I showed in my last comment. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161769/url-without-httphttps

Answer (score 0):

This WAF error is triggered because you call your website using the path `/www.tiktok.com`. The WAF interprets `www.tiktok.com` as a file name and `.com` is not permitted as a file name.
But as far as I understand the problem, this call is not intended, the WAF error is not the cause but a consequence of this wrong call, and the WAF error will be gone once you fix your link.