# Which browsers support "//" instead of "http://" and "https://"?

Tags: http, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it valid to replace  with // in a <script src=“…”>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)
>   [Absolute URLs omitting the protocol (scheme) in order to preserve the one of the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the)

I can't find anything about this in Google - it's hard to find something about "//" :)

Anyway please tell, which browsers support "//" instead of "http://" and "https://"? I'd like to use this to include images, script, styles etc. But is it safe? Is there a browser that doesn't support this and I need provide a protocol?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute URLs omitting the protocol (scheme) in order to preserve the one of the current page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the) and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http

Answer (score 15):

All browsers support it, it's safe - [RFC 3986 Section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) (or view [txt version of RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) and go to 4.2) specifies use of the [protocal relative url](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) and it is utilised in the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) where there have been no reported issues with the technique. If there was a problem with using this cross-browser, the community would have picked it up by now.

Edit: Even [WikiMedia](http://blog.wikimedia.org/2011/09/27/protocol-relative-urls-enabled-on-all-wikimedia-foundation-wikis/) use it