# Chrome issue with Modernizr and jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, modernizr, html5boilerplate

I'm working on HTML5 Boilerplate template and Modernizr. While testing some features, I tried to put in action some polyfills.
Ok, everything seems to work well, but Chrome get an error: it seems to try loading jQuery imediately after Modernizr, even if It shouldn't! In fact there is no script tag below Modernizr... What is Chrome doing?

[image: The image shows Chrome Dev Tools]

Comment: Is this an actual screenshot?

Comment: yes, it is. taken from developer tools as is

Comment: SOLVED! Chrome works fine if the web page is online. The error pops up only when I open the local copy of the file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're loading //ajax.googleapis.com.

It needs to be either http: or https:

Then it will work locally.

I'm currently trying to figure out an automatic way around this. Like... if https capable then https: else http:

Solution: Ok, you can either write a JS one-liner ternary to detect the file: protocol, then assign https: or http:, or you can simply run your site through a server like WAMP or something and it will detect the protocol.

https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/doc/faq.md

Comment: To be fair, I think it's not the protocol relative-url that causes the error but that it's not running on a server. `file:` is actually the right protocol that's being used. But yeah, http or https help here :)

Comment: Haha :D Nah, just visited the link you posted in the HTML5 Boilerplate's issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think drublic is correct. It seems like you are opening that page from local disk and not through a webserver.

And if you don't specify the protocol(scheme) in a linked resource, the browser will use the same protocol as the hosting page. So using `//ajax.googleapis.com...` is correct and there is no need for special scripts to infer the protocol to use.

here is a related [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the)

which points to this [blog post](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)