# code works at jsfiddle but not on my site

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

here are three sections to jsfiddle CSS, Javascript and HTML so there should be a way to have an HTML file with three sections which say Drop CSS code here, Drop HTML Here and Drop Javascript here. It doesn't work yet but currently I have

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Some Title</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

<!-- CSS Section From JSfiddle Goes Here -->

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js">           </script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

// Javascript Section From JSfiddle Goes Here

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- HTML Section From JSfiddle Goes Here -->

</body>
</html>
```

It seems like this would be an easy thing do do mindlessly like it could be automated or can it ?
Seems like a lot of people are are finding the examples at JSfiddle not helpful because there is some magic going on at JSfiddle which they are not sharing with us.

Comment: If you're pasting from jsfiddle directly, you probably need to cleanup the code and remove invisible special characters. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12719859/825789

Comment: is it the missing `https:` before the script tag for jquery-ui?

Comment: @zoli nope - http://stackoverflow.com/q/4978235/1499781

Comment: So what is the problem if you do this? Please remember that "doesn't work" is never a good description of a problem. What goes wrong exactly?

Comment: The last character is an utf8 char. remove it

Comment: Also remember to include the reset CSS if you used the Normalized CSS function.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this pretty easily. Save your fiddle and then click the share button. Take the full screen edit URL and paste it into a new tab. Right click in the main area where the example is and view the source. Save that and you have a working copy.

Comment: That didn't work for me (using Chrome). My code was added dynamically inside an iframe, and view source didn't show that (but inspecting the DOM did).

Comment: I was using Chrome and it worked just as it did in the output frame at JSfiddle.

Comment: My bad. I was using the `/embedded/result` URL, instead of just `/embedded`.