# CSS simple make my background 100% (autofit browser)?

Tags: html, css

I have some problem with my CSS :

My coding so far :

```
#leftcolumn {
    background: url('SlicingImage/action_bar.jpg');
    background-repeat:none;
    float:left;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="containerleft">
        <div id="leftcolumn"  >
            <p><img src="SlicingImage/alacards_logo.png"/></p>
            <ul>
            <li class="separator"></li>            
            <li class="buttons">home</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">users</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">tutorial</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">issuers</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">merchants</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">partners</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">high light</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">news</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">contact us</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class="bottom"></li>     
            </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
```

If I run this code, result : [BG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJPSV.png) but I want that small gray area covered like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfzgi.jpg)

If I delete

> background: url('SlicingImage/action_bar.jpg');

become like [BG2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMzK3.png)

I tried add that class="bottom", but not like what I want (must define height manually)

Comment: I don't realy understand your goal. Where did you add the class="bottom" ?

Comment: You are missing a UL tag around your LI tags.

Comment: I tried to edit his code for that but it seems he refused my edit :(

Comment: jsfiddle plzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: @chadocat at the bottom of my list (see my HTML code)

Comment: @haukurhaf I must add UL tag? and where to put the pic then?

Comment: oh ok, sorry didn't see. do you have css code for that class? For the UL tag just accept my edit

Comment: `.bottom{
 margin: none;
 width: 180px;
 height: 100px;
}`

Comment: @denkey [link](http://jsfiddle.net/89kHx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your background it is not showing because the z-index. Try to put a higher one

Comment: I tried that z-index but still the same, and I tried put the pic at containerLeft and still no effect

Answer (score 0):

Try giving width to your ul and margin:auto;

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 750px;
}
```

Comment: What didn't work? giving width and margin:auto; to ul

Answer (score 0):

[Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/vLXP2/):

```
#leftcolumn {
    background: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTFMUprTNP6nK2r2QxbZ-ls7YlgiVenNuwCBkXwX-keeE96iOradptCHPLZ);
    background-repeat:none;
    float:left;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

It must be something odd in your button and/or separator classes.

NOTE: I used some random pink background image that I found with Google image search.

Comment: I tried too and it works in jsfiddle but at my browser still the same if I run my code..

Comment: Sounds like you should take a look at this: [code works at JSFiddle, but not on my site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942633/code-works-at-jsfiddle-but-not-on-my-site).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: After I put `</p>` after `</ul>`, will give me the result I want

```
<div id="containerleft">
        <div id="leftcolumn"  >
            <p><img src="SlicingImage/alacards_logo.png"/>
            <ul>
            <li class="separator"></li>            
            <li class="buttons">home</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">users</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">tutorial</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">issuers</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">merchants</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">partners</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">high light</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">news</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class= "buttons">contact us</li>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <li class="bottom"></li>     
            </ul>
            </p>
        </div>
       </div>
```