# Why does the CDN's have 2 // instead of http or https in front of the URL

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, cdn

I don't understand that why I look at the following website for a CDN, the URL's start with a double "//".  I have seen this on JQuery and Bootstrap.  Is it up to the person to put http:// or https://?

http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change all my http:// links to just //?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a [protocol relative URL](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/):

> If the browser is viewing that current page in through HTTPS, then it’ll request that asset with the HTTPS protocol, otherwise it’ll typically* request it with HTTP. This prevents that awful “This Page Contains Both Secure and Non-Secure Items” error message in IE, keeping all your asset requests within the same protocol.

Answer (score 2):

It's just like omitting the domain: `href="/folder/file.html"` where the browsers just assumes the current domain.

In your case the browser will assume the current protocol.

[Absolute URLs omitting the protocol (scheme) in order to preserve the one of the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the)