# Why using href="// instead of href="http:// in HTML?

Tags: html, uri, protocol-relative

Why using `<link href="//something.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` instead of using `http://` or `https://` before the domain name?

If we use `href=//` does it changes with link? Like while in SSL mode will it automatically be changed to `https://`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it will use the current protocol.

i.e. if the current page is `https` it will access the `href` using `https`.

If `http` then the link is accessed over plain `http`.

This will prevent browser warnings if the hosting page is `https` and will be more secure than a plain `http` link.

Comment: "This will prevent browser warnings" if the destination host is also configured to correctly serve the resource via SSL. If it's not, then the behaviors range from timeouts to SSL certificate warnings to 404s.

Comment: This will only work if the domain of the resource supports the same protocol as the hosting page is being accessed under.

Answer (score 5):

It's just as you guess: using href="//..." without specifying the URI scheme allows it to dynamically match whichever protocol was used to access the resource, for example http or https.

It's really just an example of a relative path, but one that is relative to the protocol.

Source: the IETF's [URI syntax documentation](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), sections 3.1 (Scheme) & 4.2 (relative reference)