# Difference Between // and http://

Tags: http, url, https, protocols

I know that `HTTP` is hyper text transfer protocol, and I know that's how (along with `HTTPS`) one accesses a website. However, what does just a `//` do? For instance, to access Google's copy of jQuery, one would use the url `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`, as opposed to `http://...`.

What exactly is the difference? What does just `//` indicate?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why using href="// instead of href="http:// in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293029/why-using-href-instead-of-href-http-in-html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By saying on `//` it means use whatever protocol (IE: http vs https) your user is currently hittin for that resource.

So you don't have to worry about dealing with http: vs https: management yourself.

Avoiding potential browser security warnings. It would be good practice to stick with this approach.

For example: If your user is accessing `http://yourdomain/` that script file would automatically be treated as `http://ajax.googleapis.com/...`

Answer (score 3):

if your current request is http

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

will be treated as

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

if your current request is https

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

will be treated as

```
 https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```