# How to run JSBin code on your computer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsbin

I copied code from [This JSBin Project](http://jsbin.com/seqola/2/edit?html,css,js,output) on to my desktop into 3 files: index.html, style.css, script.js

I also included the lines in index.html:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

but the script and style files don't seem to work when i open index.html in browser.

Comment: it looks like it should work correctly, did you copy the CSS and JS in the JSBin, and put it in style.css and script.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsBin by default omits the `http:` in the URI <sup>see more about [protocol relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the)</sup>

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you need to add it:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and so for all other `script` and `link` tags (if you're viewing your page from `file:` environment)

See this jsBin http://jsbin.com/kumoyogegu/1/edit go to File > Download > and run it from desktop.

<sub>(Otherwise, by omitting `http:` you should correctly see your pages once uploaded to a **live server** or working from **localhost**)</sub>

Comment: thanks. now I see the style. I don't think js is working though. because I don't see the small 3-horizontal-line button, when you press, sidebar opens, that functionality does not work.

Comment: @Awesome_girl works for me. I went to File > Download (in jsBin) and it works out of the box: http://jsbin.com/kumoyogegu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: oh my bad,  the side bar feature only works when the output window size is small.

Comment: @Awesome_girl yes, you need to resize the window ;) Happy coding