# Why is Font Awesome not working with Bootstrap in JSFiddle?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, jsfiddle

I created a JSFiddle trying to show a problem I'm having with FontAwesome and it seems Font Awesome is not working at all in JSFiddle when I add Bootstrap. Here's the example:

https://jsfiddle.net/pupeno/jjjesyvt/

The code is very simple:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/css">Left</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </nav>

<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

Comment: Should the url not be url('http: //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'); ? (added http: in front)

Comment: @Laurent no, you can skip http: so that the browser will use http or https accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the

Comment: k thanks for the info ;)

Comment: Check whether you are included Font Awesome files

Comment: @ArunKumarM I have included the font awesome css file.

Comment: It´s working the font awesome..what is not working is the responsive menu. - https://jsfiddle.net/jjjesyvt/5/

Comment: You can see it here : https://jsfiddle.net/jjjesyvt/6/

Comment: @LuisP.A. ah, the margin was wrong, so, yes, font awesome is not working on the navbar.

Comment: Ah, the problem was that the font icon was not in an a.

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome appears to be working fine - it's your markup that's problematic.

1. When you have a fixed top navbar, you need to push the contents down by at least 50 pixels, not by 10 - so the `.fa-camera-retro` is being hidden by the navbar

   *Use this*:

   ```css
   body { margin-top: 60px; }
   ```

   *Instead of this*:

   ```css
   body { margin: 10px; }
   ```
2. If you replace the FA icon in the navbar-right, with just plain text, you'll notice that doesn't show up either - for bootstrap styles to take affect in the navbar, they need to be in an `a` tag.

   *Use this*:

   ```html
   <li class="active"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
   ```

   *Instead of this*:

   ```html
   <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></li>
   ```

#### [Working Demo in Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/jjjesyvt/11/)