# Force remove link protocol (not relative)

Tags: html

Is there a way to create an absolute link without a protocol **without** using `//`?
For example, From the website `https://example.com` have a link that leads to `example2.com.` `//` does not work in this case because the first link has the `https` protocol while the second does not.

Comment: Have a look at [\[ this \]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179717/1620779) answer.

Comment: no, because example2.com does not have a protocol so it wouldn't work

Comment: You maybe looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the)

Comment: As I said, // is protocol relative, which I do not want