# SSL Partially encrypted

Tags: ssl

I am new with SSL. I got a standard SSL installed in my server, but when I go to my shopping cart, it says that it's only partially encrypted. Chrome even crosses out HTTPS in the url location bar. What I understand, that there are some http links in that page (images, js), so are there any tools to check for that? Workarounds? I looked manually and found 1-2 images using HTTP instead of HTTPS in that page, can it really be a reason to block SSL?? 
Please help,crossed HTTPS link on the page looks worse than no HTTPS at all..

I also have read, that it stops (showing partial SSL) by itself sometimes.. so wonder maybe there is a time frame or smth effecting it..

UPDATE: figured myself...it was javascript using widget (using HTTP), disabling it solved a problem. Now I am not sure how to close this ticket :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **scheme-relative** URLs (they are relative to the  `http`/`https` part). This makes them protocol-independent, and your problems should be solved. For example, instead of:

```
<img src="http://example.com/path/to/image"/>
```

Use

```
<img src="//example.com/path/to/image"/>
```

#### Recommended reading

- [Network-Path Reference URI / Scheme relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583103/scheme-relative-urls)
- [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

Answer (score 1):

another possible cause of the error is the programmatic setting of an iframe's src-attribute to 'about:blank'. the effect is observable in ff 3.6.x & 4 and ie 8.

best regards, carsten