# Can a URL start with "//"?

Tags: http, url, ssl, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it valid to replace  with // in a <script src=“…”>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

We have a site on http[s]://A.example.com/ that references some resources (JS and CSS) on http[s]://A.example.com/

It makes sense, and avoids some browser warnings, if the same scheme is used when referencing the resources as the main site A is using. Site A uses PHP, so we can programmaticly detect the current scheme (http or https) and insert that into the header of the page.

However, we have found that just using '//' instead of the scheme also works.

So site A may reference "//B.example.com/theme/main.css" without a problem in all browsers we have tried, regardless of whether we go to site A using http or https.

My question is: is this a valid URL? It seems to work, but I cannot find anyone else doing it, and I cannot find any examples of this being suggested or recommended.

Comment: Just a note - this is always going to be in the header of a web page, so will always be in the context of a parent page. I am not typing "//example.com" into a browser and expecting it to know I want the "http" scheme.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http), see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/960111/398242, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187035/what-is-the-difference-between-http-and-in-web-development?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583103/network-path-reference-uri-scheme-relative-urls

Comment: I didn't see that - searching on different keywords. Thanks - the application and answer is spot-on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. It is called a protocol-relative URL. See also [Can I change all my http:// links to just //?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4831741/1048572)

Comment: Consider voting to close as a duplicate so that we don't detract attention from the many existing valuable answers. If not, please consider making your answer self-contained.

Comment: Neh it should just be closed at minimum. Perhaps even just be deleted. @WesleyMurch

Comment: I say leave it.... I found this one first because it matched my search terms best. And now it'll lead me to the other one!