# Use of double forward slashes before a domain for hyperlinks and redirects

Tags: url, redirect, hyperlink

I have been told about a method of linking and redirecting by omitting the protocol part of a URL.

For example instead of writing `https://www.example.com` or `http://www.example.com` (thereby needing to know whether the current request or destination is `HTTPS` or not) one can simply put `//www.example.com` and the browser will *inherit* the current protocol.

Is this an acceptable practice? Are there any significant risks doing this? I have been unable to find much (if any) real literature on this (although I haven't delved into the standards document).

Comment: This has already been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583103/scheme-relative-urls

Comment: Ah, snap. Thanks for that, I must be going blind.