# HTML - using "//domain.com" instead of "https://domain.com" or "http://domain.com"

Tags: html, css, http, https, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can I change all my  links to just //?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just)
>   [Network-Path Reference URI / Scheme relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583103/network-path-reference-uri-scheme-relative-urls)

Iv seen some websites using something like this:

```
background:url(//cdn.domain.com/images/bg-normal.png)
```

Notice the "//", which the browser automatically translates to "https://" if the page if using HTTPS, and translates to "http://" if the page if using HTTP.

Is it only the modern browsers who supports this notation?

Is it recommended to use this notation, or should I hardcode https:// or http:// in the CSS file depending on HTTPS or HTTP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just

Comment: Sure is getting asked a lot these few weeks. I wonder what happened on the Web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Paul Irish's [blog post](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/), it works in IE as well.