# Why does my anchor tag href point a different link?

Tags: html

I have an anchor tag in my code with the `href` attribute pointing to the following link `blog.aicexperts.com`. But when I click on the link it points to `aicexperts.com/blog.aicexperts.com`, which is obviously not found since `blog.aicexperts.com` is a subdomain on its own on the server.

The problem might be in the `.htaccess` file but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the anchor tag code

```
 <li><a href="blog.aicexperts.com">Blog</a></li>
```

I expect the link to point directly to the subdomain `blog.aicexperts.com` & not `aicexperts.com/blog.aicexperts.com`

Comment: start the url with `http://` or `https://`.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute URL must start with protocol: `http://` or `https://` or `//` ([Scheme Relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583103/network-path-reference-uri-scheme-relative-urls)).

So, your anchor tag should looks eg. like this:

```html
<a href="http://blog.aicexperts.com">Blog</a>
```