# why do I keep seeing "//" instead of "http://" for resources lately?

Tags: html, xhtml, web

I saw more an more Javascript files and pictures and CSS loaded like this:

```
src="//somepath"
```

instead of

```
src="http://somepath"
```

What is this and what does it mean? Is there any documentation to it?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using // in a <script>'s source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458735/using-in-a-scripts-source)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called protocol-relative URLs. Paul Irish has written a nice [blog post](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) about it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's weird though, because I only saw this a few months back ... or maybe I wasn't paying enough attention :).

Comment: +1 for the link, I've added that to an answer of mine on the same topic from early last year.