# http://foo.com vs. //foo.com in <a> tag?

Tags: http, hyperlink, https

I found lots of sites using `<a href='//foo.com'>` instead of `<a href='http://foo.com'>`

Is there any difference?
What are the benefits?

When using `//` instead of `http://`, is it possible to direct them to  `https://`?

Comment: I think this has been answered before:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358609/why-do-i-keep-seeing-instead-of-http-for-resources-lately][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358609/why-do-i-keep-seeing-instead-of-http-for-resources-lately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a protocol-relative URL. Every URL such as this inherits parent document's protocol (HTTP or HTTPS). Useful if you want to serve both versions of webpage.