# Do protocol relative urls work cross-platform?

Tags: html, http, uri

I often use the `//` relative URI hack. Example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Mostly because of this post: [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http).

However, a guy I am working with on a project says this doesn't work on Mac (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) or iDevices.

Not having a Mac or said devices, I can't verify it, and it works fine on Windows. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Your guy is wrong. Protocol-relative URLs are defined on a very low level. They are not OS specific. Hang on, searching for duplicate....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing secure/insecure errors by using protocol relative URLs for image source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303633/preventing-secure-insecure-errors-by-using-protocol-relative-urls-for-image-sourc)

Comment: @Pekka: Thanks. I like this technique, even though I don't think we'll be serving anything under HTTPS.

Comment: Circumstantial evidence that mobile safari supports protocol relative URLs: http://getsatisfaction.com/viglink/topics/link_broken_in_mobile_safari

Comment: I know this thread is old and dead but just for anyone else who stumbles along here, I just tested this on a Mac and the relative URI trick doesn't work very well. It puts file:// on the front instead of the http/https you probably want. It did work in iOS7 though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't test it as I don't have a Mac, but there is no reason to believe that mac browsers do not follow [RFC 3986 Section 4.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) when resolving URLs.

Your friend probably meant something else.

Comment: I don't think he meant something else, as he said "We are doing best practices, full URL paths for anything not hosted on our site from here on out.", which I can't really disagree with, since it's a two person project and he's the leader...

Comment: @alpha have you asked him why?

Comment: Well, presumably because it doesn't work (for him) on Mac browsers and Mobile Safari. Anyway, since I'm pretty sure we won't be serving anything over HTTPS, I'll just use the http: prefix, but for future reference it would be nice to know if that is indeed the case. It seems not. Thanks.

Comment: @alpha no problem. If your colleague comes up with something substantial regarding the issue, please leave a comment here - but from all I can see, there is nothing to it