# Automatic selection : http or https javascript inclusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl, https

Is it possible to automatically detect whether or not the page is accessed via http or https and then include a https://url.js or http://url.js ?

Is javascript included via https any different? I'm talking about cache age and so on?

Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a protocol-relative link, starting with `//` instead of `http or https`:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//path/to/file.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is that supported in every browser? Interesting.

Comment: @Wesley I believe so. I think it's been part of the spec since the mid 1990's and am trying to find the W3 documentation now.

Comment: This question has a bit of interesting additional information about protocol-relative URL's when used in HTML email http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303633/preventing-secure-insecure-errors-by-using-protocol-relative-urls-for-image-sour

Comment: width domain name  will be like  `//domain.net/path/to.file.js`