# <iframe> links disappear when uploading website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So I've fully made my website, it perfect when i test it from my computer, but when i upload it to the server my iframe links Disappear. one is a youtube video and the other is a weather Widget. they appear when i click load unsafe content in the browser, i was just wonder ho to make them load all the time?

any answers you could give me would be amazing!

```
<iframe id="forecast_embed" type="text/html" frameborder="0" height="245" width="100%" src="http://forecast.io/embed/#lat=-19.135865&lon=-146.842356&name=magnetic island&units=uk"> </iframe> 

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YH7EigKVYFs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

cheers!

Comment: Your site is using https?

Comment: If the linked question doesn't match your issue this one can be reopened. Basically you have to load everything with https instead of http. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303633/preventing-secure-insecure-errors-by-using-protocol-relative-urls-for-image-sour

Comment: I figured it out! i just simply had to put a 's' after http in the link and works perfectly!  

thanks guys for the help!