# Align HTTP/HTTPS with web page's protocol?

Tags: asp.net, https

We have a lot of ASP.NET code with client URLs referencing external scripts and resources as shown. Obviously it's a facebook app but that's not really relevant to the more general question of:

**What is the smart way to switch all script and link protocols between HTTP and HTTPS to align with the protocol chosen by the user of the page?**

The user can be in unsecure mode,

`http://apps.facebook.com/app1`

or surf in secure mode

`HTTPS://apps.facebook.com/app1`

---

Samples of page content:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js">
    </script>

<% if (IsFrench) { %>
       <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/all.js"></script>
<% } else { %>
       <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<% } %>
```

[ snip ]

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com/about.aspx">Microsoft About Page</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/">Example Page</a>
```

[ snip ]

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"
        type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js">
```

[ etc... ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace "http://" with "//"
should be fine

Comment: You were the first on the draw. Thanks. In all these years, I didn't realize such as simple mechanism exists.

Comment: Does anybody know of browser compatibility issues in context of using protocol-less URLs, or is it rather safe?

Comment: Compatibility and RFC info is answered over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http/550073#550073

Answer (score 0):

Just start the links without a specified protocol - the protocol will get inherited from the page.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js">
```

This is a common technique on pages that need to be served by both `http` and `https`.

Answer (score 0):

I like the approach that Google takes with it's libraries, such as Google Analytics:

```
    (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 
              'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
```

The checks are all done on the client side. And it works if your third party scripts are not hosted at precisely the same URL when in SSL versus non-SSL.

Comment: It appears Google goes to this extent in code because they vary the subdomain name along with the protocol. I can get away without varying the domain in my scenario so likely won't use this, however I have no issue using something that's good enough for Google.  Thanks.