# node.js, socket.io with SSL

Tags: ssl, node.js, https, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to get socket.io running with my SSL certificate however, it will not connect.

I based my code off the chat example:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
/**
 * Bootstrap app.
 */
var sys = require('sys')
require.paths.unshift(__dirname + '/../../lib/');

/**
* Module dependencies.
*/

var express = require('express')
  , stylus = require('stylus')
  , nib = require('nib')
  , sio = require('socket.io');

/**
 * App.
 */
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('../key').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('../crt').toString();
var ca = fs.readFileSync('../intermediate.crt').toString();

var app = express.createServer({key:privateKey,cert:certificate,ca:ca });

/**
 * App configuration.
 */

...

/**
 * App routes.
 */

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { layout: false });
});

/**
 * App listen.
 */

app.listen(443, function () {
  var addr = app.address();
  console.log('   app listening on http://' + addr.address + ':' + addr.port);
});

/**
 * Socket.IO server (single process only)
 */

var io = sio.listen(app,{key:privateKey,cert:certificate,ca:ca});
...
```

If I remove the SSL code it runs fine, however with it I get a request to `http://domain.example/socket.io/1/?t=1309967919512`

Note it's not trying HTTPS, which causes it to fail.

I'm testing on chrome, since it is the target browser for this application.

I apologize if this is a simple question, I'm a node/socket.io newbie.

Comment: Is your client trying to connect to a 'wss://' prefixed URI.

Comment: nope it doesnt get there, it makes the request to  http://domain.com/socket.io/1/?t=1309967919512 then dies.

Comment: How are you specifying the address to connect to? "domain.com" sounds like a placeholder in the socket.io client-side library. Can you post your client Javascript code that you are using to connect?

Comment: the project is on github: https://github.com/BCCasino/BCCasino

Comment: basically becasue its node.js socket.io magically handles the client side stuff, all you do is run socket.connect

Comment: in github the code in question is test2.js and index.jade (backend and frontend respetively)

Comment: I was trying to  make a connection using wss uri it gives me URISyntaxException. Any idea why?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Use a secure URL for your initial connection, i.e. instead of "http://" use "https://". If the WebSocket transport is chosen, then Socket.IO should automatically use "wss://" (SSL) for the WebSocket connection too.

**Update**:

You can also try creating the connection using the 'secure' option:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://localhost', {secure: true});
```

Comment: we do this.  we goto https : // www.thebitcoinwheel.com and it still makes a request to http automatically, this is something with the socket.io code and is the point of the question.

Comment: `{secure: true}` should not be needed if you specify 'https' in the url. Here is an excerpt from socket.io client source 
`secure: 'https' == uri.protocol`
(version 0.9.16), it sets secure option to true if https is detected in the url.

Comment: I tried this with an https URL and indeed `{secure: true}` was not required to function correctly.

Comment: I believe it would be prudent to assure that the connection is secure by using both secure:true and issuing an https url to the client side. This way no matter what you know it will be a secure connection.

Answer (score 75):

The following is how I set up to set it up with express:

```
    var app = require('express')();
    var https = require('https');
    var fs = require( 'fs' );
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('./test_key.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./test_cert.crt'),
        ca: fs.readFileSync('./test_ca.crt'),

        requestCert: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }

    var server = https.createServer(options, app);
    server.listen(8080);
    

    
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        // code goes here...
    });
    
    app.get("/", function(request, response){
        // code goes here...
    })
```

**Update :** for those using lets encrypt use this

```
var server = https.createServer({ 
                key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
                cert: fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem') 
             }, app);
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks for saving my time.

Comment: worked good for me after a bit of trial and error with the certs

Comment: This solution worked perfect for me, thanks. If you're using the free certs from letsencrypt.org then you can use the following code..

`var server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.name/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.name/cert.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.name/chain.pem'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
},app);
server.listen(3000);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It has been of tremendous help to me.

Comment: I cracked my head looking for a solution in SocketIO and the issue was to config express, fantastic...

Comment: "`rejectUnauthorized: false` WARNING: it leaves you vulnerable to MITM attacks!"

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm with letsencrypt and .pem files

Comment: This almost worked for me. I had to move the line `var io = require('socket.io')(server);` AFTER the one in which the server was declared though.

Answer (score 36):

On the same note, if your server supports both `http` and `https` you can connect using:

```
var socket = io.connect('//localhost');
```

to [auto detect the browser scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503946/shorthand-http-as-for-script-and-link-tags-anyone-see-use-this-before) and connect using http/https accordingly. when in https, the transport will be secured by default, as connecting using

```
var socket = io.connect('https://localhost');
```

will use secure web sockets - `wss://` (the  `{secure: true}` is redundant).

for more information on how to serve both http and https easily using the same node server check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285180/use-both-http-and-https-for-socket-io#22286291).

Answer (score 14):

If your server certificated file is not trusted, (for example, you may generate the keystore by yourself with **keytool** command in java), you should add the extra option rejectUnauthorized

```
var socket = io.connect('https://localhost', {rejectUnauthorized: false});
```

Comment: would be appreciated if you added an example explaining how you used the keytool to create that key for node. 'Cause keys are so complicated and there just aren't enough tutorials about it.

Comment: keytool is a tool inside the Java Development Kit (JDK). you can referer this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/keytool.htm#JSWOR-GUID-5990A2E4-78E3-47B7-AE75-6D1826259549

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your needs, you could allow both secure and unsecure connections and still only use one Socket.io instance.

You simply have to instanciate two servers, one for HTTP and one for HTTPS, then attach those servers to the Socket.io instance.

Server side :

```
// needed to read certificates from disk
const fs          = require( "fs"    );

// Servers with and without SSL
const http        = require( "http"  )
const https       = require( "https" );
const httpPort    = 3333;
const httpsPort   = 3334;
const httpServer  = http.createServer();
const httpsServer = https.createServer({
    "key" : fs.readFileSync( "yourcert.key" ),
    "cert": fs.readFileSync( "yourcert.crt" ),
    "ca"  : fs.readFileSync( "yourca.crt"   )
});
httpServer.listen( httpPort, function() {
    console.log(  `Listening HTTP on ${httpPort}` );
});
httpsServer.listen( httpsPort, function() {
    console.log(  `Listening HTTPS on ${httpsPort}` );
});

// Socket.io
const ioServer = require( "socket.io" );
const io       = new ioServer();
io.attach( httpServer  );
io.attach( httpsServer );

io.on( "connection", function( socket ) {

    console.log( "user connected" );
    // ... your code

});
```

Client side :

```
var url    = "//example.com:" + ( window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "3334" : "3333" );
var socket = io( url, {
    // set to false only if you use self-signed certificate !
    "rejectUnauthorized": true
});
socket.on( "connect", function( e ) {
    console.log( "connect", e );
});
```

If your NodeJS server is different from your Web server, you will maybe need to set some CORS headers. So in the server side, replace:

```
const httpServer  = http.createServer();
const httpsServer = https.createServer({
    "key" : fs.readFileSync( "yourcert.key" ),
    "cert": fs.readFileSync( "yourcert.crt" ),
    "ca"  : fs.readFileSync( "yourca.crt"   )
});
```

With:

```
const CORS_fn = (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"     , "*"    );
    res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" );
    res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"    , "*"    );
    res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"    , "*"    );
    if ( req.method === "OPTIONS" ) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
        return;
    }
};
const httpServer  = http.createServer( CORS_fn );
const httpsServer = https.createServer({
        "key" : fs.readFileSync( "yourcert.key" ),
        "cert": fs.readFileSync( "yourcert.crt" ),
        "ca"  : fs.readFileSync( "yourca.crt"   )
}, CORS_fn );
```

And of course add/remove headers and set the values of the headers according to your needs.

Answer (score 4):

check this.configuration..

```
app = module.exports = express();
var httpsOptions = { key: fs.readFileSync('certificates/server.key'), cert: fs.readFileSync('certificates/final.crt') };        
var secureServer = require('https').createServer(httpsOptions, app);
io = module.exports = require('socket.io').listen(secureServer,{pingTimeout: 7000, pingInterval: 10000});
io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling","websocket","polling", "htmlfile"]);
secureServer.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Server-side:

```
import http from 'http';
import https from 'https';
import SocketIO, { Socket } from 'socket.io';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

import { logger } from '../../utils';

const port: number = 3001;

const server: https.Server = https.createServer(
  {
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../ssl/cert.pem')),
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../ssl/key.pem'))
  },
  (req: http.IncomingMessage, res: http.ServerResponse) => {
    logger.info(`request.url: ${req.url}`);

    let filePath = '.' + req.url;
    if (filePath === './') {
      filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './index.html');
    }

    const extname = String(path.extname(filePath)).toLowerCase();
    const mimeTypes = {
      '.html': 'text/html',
      '.js': 'text/javascript',
      '.json': 'application/json'
    };

    const contentType = mimeTypes[extname] || 'application/octet-stream';

    fs.readFile(filePath, (error: NodeJS.ErrnoException, content: Buffer) => {
      if (error) {
        res.writeHead(500);
        return res.end(error.message);
      }
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
      res.end(content, 'utf-8');
    });
  }
);

const io: SocketIO.Server = SocketIO(server);

io.on('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('updateTemplate', data => {
    logger.info(data);
    socket.emit('updateTemplate', { random: data });
  });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`Https server is listening on https://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Client-side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Websocket Secure Connection</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button id='btn'>Send Message</button>
    <ul id='messages'></ul>
  </div>
  <script src='../../../node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js'></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function onload() {
      const socket = io('https://localhost:3001');
      socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });

      socket.on('updateTemplate', function onUpdateTemplate(data) {
        console.log(data)
        createMessage(JSON.stringify(data));
      });
      const $btn = document.getElementById('btn');
      const $messages = document.getElementById('messages');

      function sendMessage() {
        socket.emit('updateTemplate', Math.random());
      }

      function createMessage(msg) {
        const $li = document.createElement('li');
        $li.textContent = msg;
        $messages.appendChild($li);
      }

      $btn.addEventListener('click', sendMessage);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But how do you make port 3001 secure? Only 443 is secure on my VPS. When I try and use 3001, I get a red polling link in Chrome Dev tools. This is because the port is insecure.

Answer (score 2):

For enterprise applications it should be noted that you should not be handling https in your code. It should be auto upgraded via IIS or nginx. The app shouldn't know about what protocols are used.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone need a shorter form

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path-to/ssl.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path-to/ssl.cert')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my nginx config file and iosocket code. Server(express) is listening on port 9191.  It works well:
nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/rdist;

    location /user/ {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:9191;
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:9191;
    }
    location /auth/ {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:9191;
    }

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        if (!-e $request_filename){
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
        }
    }
    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:9191/socket.io/;
    }


    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/sslcert/xxx.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/sslcert/xxx.key;

}
```

Server:

```
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    handleUserConnect(socket)

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
   handleUserDisConnect(socket)
  });
})

server.listen(9191, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on port 9191')
})
```

Client(react):

```
    const socket = io.connect('', { secure: true, query: `userId=${this.props.user._id}` })

        socket.on('notifications', data => {
            console.log('Get messages from back end:', data)
            this.props.mergeNotifications(data)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Server side:

```
var ssl_options = {
    ca: [fs.readFileSync('../ssl/cert1.crt'), fs.readFileSync('../ssl/cert2.crt'), fs.readFileSync('../ssl/cert3.crt')],
    key: fs.readFileSync('../ssl/xxx.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../ssl/xxx.example.crt'),
};
var wssServer = https.createServer(ssl_options,app);  // Express app
wssServer.listen(4433, '0.0.0.0');
global.io = require("socket.io")();
io.listen(wssServer);
io.on( "connection", function( socket ) {
    console.log( "user connected" );
});
```

Client-side (no luck with the built-in WebSocket API):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
   const socket = io("https://xxx.example:4433",{ transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get this to work with Debian 10, ISPConfig 3 and Let's Encrypt. Took me a while to work out the specifics. Maybe this saves someone else some time…

Server-side:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
const https_options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/clients/client1/web1/ssl/your-domain.com-le.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/clients/client1/web1/ssl/your-domain.com-le.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/root/.acme.sh/your-domain.example/fullchain.cer'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}
const server = https.createServer(https_options, app);
server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server started ok');
});
const io = socketio(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "https://your-domain.example",
    },
    secure: true
});
io.on('connection', (sock) => {
    console.log('someone connected');
}
```

Client-side:

```
const sock = io('https://your-domain.example:3000/');
sock.on('status', (text) => {
    add_text($('#status'), text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this:

```
const server = require("https");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const io = new Server({
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
    },
  });

  const folder = path.join(__dirname, "ssl");
  const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(folder, "server_key.pem"),
    "utf8"
  );
  const certificate = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(folder, "server_cert.pem"),
    "utf8"
  );

  const SSL_CONFIG= {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: [certificate],
    requestCert: false,certificate, tested and it works
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  };

  const WEB_SERVER = server.createServer(SSL_CONFIG);

  WEB_SERVER.listen(1102);
  io.listen(WEB_SERVER);
```