# Socket.IO chat app + SSL + NGINX

Tags: ssl, nginx, socket.io

I have a chat app based on Node/Socket.IO running behind a NGINX proxy.

Now that I am switching to SSL, I wonder if it is sufficient if I only have NGINX do the handshake and all, or do I have configure Socket.IO to use SSL as well (-> [node.js, socket.io with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599470/node-js-socket-io-with-ssl))?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx 1.4 supports websockets. you can use nginx for SSL termination. no need to add SSL in socket.io or nodejs