# WebRTC: Conflict with HTTPS mode in SimpleWebRTC

Tags: webrtc

I want to develop a Video Chat application. So I started to check the SimpleWebRTC JS Framework. When I share my screen, it requires HTTPS mode. If I hosted the files in SSL domain. But the Socket js (included file) is in an insecure domain.

http://signaling.simplewebrtc.com:8888/socket.io/1/?t=139165345345345

If I change the protocol into HTTPS then it doesn't return response.

Please advice.

Comment: I don't have time to investigate here, but it looks like you should just switch to using secure sockets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599470/node-js-socket-io-with-ssl

Answer (score 2):

You can host the socket.io.js library, which is the simpleWebRTC signalling server yourself on a node server, and point that as your signalling server.
That worked for me.