# Node.js HTTPS not working

Tags: node.js, https

I'm trying to create HTTPS server with Node.js. I have followed some instructions from web and end up with this code:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('D:\\NodeJs\\HTTPS\\keys\\pvtkey.pem', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('D:\\NodeJs\\HTTPS\\keys\\cert.pem', 'utf8'),
  requestCert: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {

  if (req.client.authorized) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        res.end('{"status":"approved"}');
    } else {
        res.writeHead(401, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        res.end('{"status":"denied"}');
    }

}).listen(443);

console.log('start listing');
```

When trying access from Chrome, I get the following error:

> SSL connection error Unable to make a secure connection to the server.
>   This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client
>   authentication certificate that you don't have. Error code:
>   ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Any advice?

Comment: You **MUST** have a valid SSL certificate installed on your server in order to utilize HTTPS connections.

Comment: Read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599470/node-js-socket-io-with-ssl

Comment: I have changed https options to take pfx

it works but with "identity not verified"

Comment: @AhmedMetwally: "identity not verified" is a problem with your certificate. Better ask another question about this problem and don't forget to include the details of your certificate (issuer, subject, SAN...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your SSL certificate is either self signed or there is no SSL certificate available.

To bypass testing of SSL certificates you can add the following line:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you use windows server**

I suggest the following steps

**step 1:**

To buy ssl from a trusted source, I used ssls.com

**step 2:**

install ssl on iis

**step 3:**

export ssl certificate to pfx file, use digiCertUtil.exe [download here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztlwz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztlwz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpdRK.png)

**step 4:**

generate privkey.pem and fullchain.pem files use openssl

```
openssl pkcs12 -in example.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out privkey.pem -passin pass:pfx-password -passout pass:new-password

openssl pkcs12 -in example.pfx -nokeys -out fullchain.pem -passin pass:pfx-password -passout pass:new-password
```

**step 5:**

use in node.js app

```js
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem')
};


var app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hollo world')
})

https.createServer(options, app).listen(8883);
```