# Is it possible to create a "fake" socket connection to a nodejs server that is secured through SSL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, socket.io

I'm using socket.io-client to create a socket connection to my locally-running server. See my code below:

```
// Working example of connecting to a local server that is not SSL protected


var io = require('socket.io-client')
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {reconnect: true});


socket.on('connect', function(){ console.log("inside 'connect'") } );

socket.on('connection', function(){ console.log("inside 'connection'") } );

socket.on('event', function(data){ console.log("inside 'event'") } );

socket.on('disconnect', function(){ console.log("inside 'disconnect'") } );



var payload = {email: 'fake@gmail.com', password: 'tester'};
var tokens = {browserId: 'b965e554-b4d2-5d53-fd69-b2ca5483537a'};


socket.emit("publish", {logic:"user", method:"signIn"}, payload, tokens, function(err, creds) {
    console.log("inside the socket client emit callback. err: " + err);
    console.log("creds: " + creds);
});
```

Now for my problem. As I stated in the comment at the top of that code, I can connect to my local nodejs server and get the response I expect when I turn off SSL encryption on my server. As soon as I turn SSL on, I stop getting any response at all from the code above. I don't see any message in my server logs or from the command line, where I'm running the code above with **node**.

My goal is to be able to run the code above, with SSL turned on in my server, and get the same response that I get when SSL is turned off. I've tried a bunch of variations on the code I included above, such as:

- connecting to "https://localhost:3000"
- connecting to "//localhost:3000"
- connecting to "https://localhost:3443" (this is the port I have to connect to when I have the nodejs server running with SSL)
- changing {reconnect:true} to {reconnect:true,secure:true}

I'm truly stumped, and I've been doing a bunch of research on the web and on my node server. It's my company's code and I didn't originally implement the SSL components, so I've spent a few hours looking at our code and trying to understand how adding SSL changes everything. I'm also a student and have about 2 years of experience behind me, so I'm good but I'm no expert. Have I said anything above that indicates if my task is impossible to achieve, or if maybe I have just overlooked something? Any leads on things to check out would be appreciated :)

Comment: @RolandStarke There is no "client site" or client side. I'm running the script above from my terminal. When I run my server **without** SSL turned on, I get output to my terminal from the script above. With SSL turned on, I get no output to my terminal at all.

Comment: Did you provide the `key`, `cert` and `ca` in your socket server like he does? :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599470/node-js-socket-io-with-ssl cant find any docs in socket.io for ssl but maby that helps.

Comment: The server itself is definitely being provided the `key` and `cert`. I don't know what it meant by `ca`. My individual code snippet in my question doesn't provide a `key` or `cert` or anything else, other than a url to where the server should be listening