# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED comes in socket.io client side loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ssl

I have created a node server and used socket.io in my application. Since my application is running in a https, i have included the ssl certificate and key when creating the server. But when i start the node server and check the client side application it gives the error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in the console.
It will be great if someone can help me out with this. Thanks.

Below is my server side and client side codes,

**Server side server.js file**

```
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');  

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(8000);
```

**client side js files inclution**

```
<script src="https://myhost.com:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js">   </script>
<script>
  var socket = io('https://myhost.com:8000');
</script>
```

[**Error comes in the console**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9yDY.png)

Comment: maybe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599470/node-js-socket-io-with-ssl will help ... even though the accepted answer seems to be disputed

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, but in my case in server side, node server starts with no issues. When i load the socket.io.js file from the client side only the error comes.

Comment: so `var socket = io('https://myhost.com:8000', {secure: true});` doesn't help you?

Comment: @JaromandaX no because the error comes when loading the js file.

var socket = io('https://myhost.com:8000', {secure: true}); 
comes after loading the js file

Comment: oh, so your server doesn't know how to serve that file - nothing in your server code suggests it knows what to do for that request

Comment: yeah that's the issue.my server code doesn't give me any clue about that

Comment: clue? OK ... here's a clue ... which part of your server code do you think knows how to deal with a GET request for `/socket.io/socket.io.js` - nothing you posted suggests your server code deals with such a request

Comment: yeah i haven't included that part of code because when `var io = require('socket.io')(server);` runs it creates a `/socket.io/socket.io.js` file right ? so i should be able to include it in the client side code...sorry if i'm doing anything wrong here (i'm quite new to node.js/socket.io)