# Why my socket.io not working properly?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i have setup my chat application on https server but it's not working when i try it with https it's working fine for https i have get this error :

GET https://example.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1507097218133-25 net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE socket.io.js:2919

Comment: May be a certificate issue. Did you mean to say you got it working with HTTP and not HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add ssl certificate of your domain not self created because self created only works for localhost not for main site.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

[node.js, socket.io with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599470/node-js-socket-io-with-ssl)

You also want to make sure you prefix URLs with wss:\\

Comment: i think you not read properly my question i am not talking about localhost it's on live server