# Socket connection is not established on AWS EC2

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I have deployed my code with docker image and here is the code for the socket connection.

I got SUCCESSFUL connection in the local system but when I deploy the same code on EC2 it gives me the following error:
[image]

I'm using express server.

**Server:**

```
var serverIO = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(serverIO);
io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Client connected...', client.id);
})

var server = serverIO.listen(config.app.port, function(){
    console.log('server running on port:', config.app.port)
})
```

**Client:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div id="future"></div>
        <form id="form" id="chat_form">
            <input id="chat_input" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
 // var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000'); //here I got connection 
 var socket = io.connect('https://liveURL:8000'); //here I got error
    socket.on('connect', function(data) {
        socket.emit('join', {email: "user1@example.com"});
    });

  socket.on('broad', function(data) {
        console.log(data)
         $('#future').append(data+ "<br/>");
   });

  socket.on("new_msg", function(data) {
    console.log("here")
    alert(data.msg);
   })

 $('form').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var message = $('#chat_input').val();
     socket.emit('messages', {email: "user1@example.com"});
 });
</script>
```

Comment: try socket.on('error' maybe you will get the msg

Comment: @joyBlanks No error printed on server side

Comment: one thing more :) you hide IP in the code but printed red list in the console screenshot ;)

Comment: @Adiii That's wrong URL BTW.

Comment: then it's fine, just to make you sure about the image :)

Comment: @Adiii Thanks, man. I appreciate it.

Comment: @HarshPatel answer is updated. you should better to try with `http`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the connection `secure` flag to true.

```
 var socket = io.connect('https://liveURL:8000',{secure: true}); //here I got error
    socket.on('connect', function(data) {
        socket.emit('join', {email: "user1@example.com"});
    });
```

You can check the offical documentation.

```
{
  headers: /* the headers sent as part of the handshake */,
  time: /* the date of creation (as string) */,
  address: /* the ip of the client */,
  xdomain: /* whether the connection is cross-domain */,
  secure: /* whether the connection is secure */,
  issued: /* the date of creation (as unix timestamp) */,
  url: /* the request URL string */,
  query: /* the query object */
}
```

Or if you are using express on the server side then you can look [here](https://chrislarson.me/blog/ssl-nodejs-express-and-socketio/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599470/node-js-socket-io-with-ssl)

**Updated:**

I saw that there is no **SSL Configuration** on your server-side so `https` will not work.

Try with http instead

```
io.connect('http://liveserver:8000')
```

Comment: but you did not initiate server on server-side with ssl?

Comment: try to connect with live server like `io.connect('http://liveserver:8000')`

Comment: I don't have currently SSL certificate. so I can no tinitiate server with ssl

Comment: `io.connect('http://liveserver:8000')` gives the same error like in image

Comment: then how you are trying to connect the client with `https`? so try to connect with http instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199175/discussion-between-adiii-and-harsh-patel).