# How to get https on socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, electron

currently I use

```js
let connectTo = "http://myip:myport";
var socket = io.connect(connectTo, {secure: true});
```

on client side, and

```js
const port = myport;
const io = require('socket.io')(port);
```

on server side, I want to use `https://` instead of `http://`, how do I do that? I also heard I need a certificate thing, how do I get that? and how to set it up? cause stupid anti viruses think the socket.io is "dangerous" when it isnt.. (the client side is on my electron application)

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599470/node-js-socket-io-with-ssl To get ssl sertificate use https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

Comment: This seems far too broad, can you focus on a single issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your own https server (with appropriate certificates) and then bind socket.io to that server.   Every socket.io connection starts with an http(s) request so that's why you need that kind of server.

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('somePath/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('somePath/agent2-cert.pem')
};
const server = https.createServer(options);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(443);
```

> I also heard I need a certification thing, how to I get that?

There are lots and lots of sources.  You can start here: https://letsencrypt.org/. You will have to bind a certificate to a particular domain as that's part of the security that it delivers.

---

Then, in the client, you would connect using an `https` URL such as:

```
const socket = io('https://example.com');
```

Comment: I also do not have a domain so its a IP like `12.23.2.3.2` (example), how do I get https with certificate on that?

Comment: @Richieboi - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name.