# How to use socket.io with https

Tags: node.js, https, socket.io, lets-encrypt

I made a socket.io http server but now I want it to work with https.

I generated a certificate with letsencrypt and I want to use it for my app.

Server code

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const server = require('https').createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem')
});
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {});

io.on('connection', socket => { console.log(socket.id); });

server.listen(3000);
```

I'm using socket.io@^2.3.0 and socket.io-client@^2.4.0 for the client

When i try to connect with the client I see no connection / error on the server.

This is how the client looks

```js
const socket = require("socket.io-client")("https://example.com:3000")
socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("connected")
}
```

I've also tried with other URLs but still nothing:

```js
const socket = require("socket.io-client")("http://example.com:3000")
const socket = require("socket.io-client")("https://example.com")
const socket = require("socket.io-client")("wss://example.com:3000")
const socket = require("socket.io-client")("wss://example.com")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js, socket.io with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599470/node-js-socket-io-with-ssl)

Comment: No, as you can see in the url i'm using https in the URL, I also tried using the secure option

Comment: I would first get the exact same version number for client and server.  Socket.io is notoriously picky about client/server version numbers.

Comment: Also, I would try with WebSockets. socket.io is really outdated nowadays.