# Socket IO with cluster on https not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Based on the Socket IO documentation, I am able to use http but not https.
I am using the socket io with cluster with http its working fine but not working  when i implement https on it.

Socket IO documentation that i am using :- https://socket.io/docs/v4/cluster-adapter/

My Code is

```
const cluster = require("cluster");
const https = require("https");
var fs = require("fs");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const numCPUs = require("os").cpus().length;
const { setupMaster, setupWorker } = require("@socket.io/sticky");
const { createAdapter, setupPrimary } = require("@socket.io/cluster-adapter");
const sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("security/cert.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("security/cert.pem")
};
const options = { cors: true, origins: "*" };
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  const httpServer = https.createServer(sslOptions);

  // setup sticky sessions
  setupMaster(httpServer, {
    loadBalancingMethod: "least-connection"
  });

  setupPrimary();

  cluster.setupPrimary({
    serialization: "advanced"
  });

  httpServer.listen(8000);

  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on("exit", (worker) => {
    console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);

  const httpServer = https.createServer(sslOptions);

  const io = new Server(httpServer, options);

  // use the cluster adapter
  io.adapter(createAdapter());

  // setup connection with the primary process
  setupWorker(io);

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("connected" + process.pid);
    io.emit("data", "connected to worker: " + cluster.worker.id);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what "not working" exactly means? Do you have any error messages? What behaviour do you face and what would you expect? .

Comment: @SilvanBregy Thanks for response 
Socket IO is not connecting from client side. And also if Socket IO is running on your port then socketio.js file generated automatically  but here not showing any socketio.js file.
Same I run with http its working fine

Comment: try this answer with express.js, (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38525463/13460667). I know this is not what you asked, but you can try to find anything you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with code, the possible error could be "Secure Connection Failed" due to ssl certificate.Otherwise the same code is working for me.

Comment: Thanks @anuj 
I have tested SSL its working fine. because If I am using without clustering its working fine .

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-sticky

**this module is not compatible with an HTTPS server**