# Two forward slashes in a url/src/href attribute

Tags: html, http, https, relative-url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URI starting with two slashes … how do they behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071117/uri-starting-with-two-slashes-how-do-they-behave)
>   [Absolute URLs omitting the protocol (scheme) in order to preserve the one of the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the)
>   [shorthand  as // for script and link tags? anyone see / use this before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503946/shorthand-http-as-for-script-and-link-tags-anyone-see-use-this-before)

I was looking through the source of [HTML5 Reset](https://github.com/murtaugh/HTML5-Reset) when I noticed the [following line](https://github.com/murtaugh/HTML5-Reset/blob/master/index.html#L113):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why does the URL start with two forward slashes? Is this a shorthand for `http://`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute URLs omitting the protocol (scheme) in order to preserve the one of the current page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the), see also [Can I change all my http:// links to just //?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src=“http://…”>?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/550038/90527) [URI starting with two slashes ... how do they behave?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4071117/)

Answer (score 252, accepted):

## The "two forward slashes" are a common shorthand for "request the referenced resource using whatever protocol is being used to load the current page".

Best known as "protocol relative URLs", they are particularly useful when elements — such as the JS file in your example — could be served and/or requested from either a `http` or a `https` context. By using protocol relative URLs, you can avoid implementing

```
if (window.location.protocol === 'http:') {
    myResourceUrl = 'http://example.com/my-resource.js';
} else {
    myResourceUrl = 'https://example.com/my-resource.js';
}
```

type of logic all over your codebase (assuming, of course, that the server at `example.com` is able to serve content through both `http` and `https`).

A prominent real-world example is the Magento 1.X E-Commerce engine: for performance reasons, the category and product pages use plain `http` by default, whereas the checkout is `https` enabled.

If some resources (e.g. promotional banners in the site's header) are referenced via non protocol relative URLs (i.e. `http://example.com/banner.jpg`), customers reaching the `https` enabled checkout are greeted with a rather unfriendly

> "there are insecure elements on this page"

prompt - which, one can safely assume, isn't exactly great for business.

If the aforementioned resource is referenced via `//example.com/banner.jpg` though, the browser takes care of loading it via the proper protocol both on the plain http product/category pages and in the https-enabled checkout flow.

**tl;dr: With even the slightest possibility of a mixed http/https environment, just use the double slash/protocol relative URLs to reference resources — assuming that the host serving them supports both http and https.**

Comment: Carefull though, if you do this in SharePoint 2010 SP will automatically change the tag to be https if your content authors are authoring on a secure site for a page consumed on a public site.  The image will always be https on the http accessed url.  Confirmed with the Telerik Rad Editor....not sure about vanilla SP.

Comment: Yes, but why not a single slash?  Doesn't that do the same thing?

Comment: @mckoss : a single slash works great if the file is on the same domain. I could, of course, fetch `http(s)://mydomain.com/resource.jpg` by referencing `/resource.jpg`. For `http(s)://some-other-dudes-domain.com/other-resource.jpg`, the single slash obviously won't work.

Comment: On a minor note, the snippet above could be better implemented as: myResourceUrl = window.location.protocol + '://example.com/my-resource.js'; but of course myResourceUrl = '//example.com/my-resource.js'; is even simpler

Comment: @vzwick, When did browsers started supporting this syntax? Since IE6 era?

Comment: @Pacerier - this is standardised at least since [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-4.2), so 2005-ish. Probably worked before, too.

Comment: According to wikipedia in 2005 IE 6 was released in August 2001 and IE7 was released in October 2006. @Pacerier, if IE6 was a guess, it was accurate.

Comment: Dammit.. iOS 11.2.5 Safari will interpret `localhost` as `https:`, while pc chrome and android as `http:`.

Answer (score 16):

It will automatically add https or http, depending on how the request was made.

Comment: Its worth noting this will populate not just http or https, but also any other protocol that the browser supports. FTP for example. It tells the browser to use the same protocol that is being used. (sorry to comment on an old post!)

Comment: There's also http2 these days so there could be more fun stuff coming